# Centering Unicoded Characters In Terminal

Tags: c#, console-application

I am trying to create a TextBase Game.

Thus I wanted to add some cool art like this: [image: Cool Art]

As you can see, it sits very sadly in the top-left corner, like it should.

**BUT** I wish it to be in the horizontal-center.

Thus I tried out my thoughts:

1. Subtract the console Window-Width by the contents length and divide that to half and set its cursor there.

   `Console.SetCursorPosition((Console.WindowWidth - contents.Length) / 2, Console.CursorTop);`

This thought gives me a Negative value so my logic is flawed :C

2. Try using String formatting

   `Console.WriteLine(String.Format("{0," + ((Console.WindowWidth / 2) + (contents.Length / 2)) + "}", contents));`

This though seems to only accept regular characters.

**What** am I missing here?

Heres the text for Replicating:

```
▄▄▌ ▐ ▄▌▄▄▄ .▄▄▌   ▄▄·       • ▌ ▄ ·. ▄▄▄ .    ▄▄▄▄▄          
██· █▌▐█▀▄.▀·██•  ▐█ ▌▪▪     ·██ ▐███▪▀▄.▀·    •██  ▪         
██▪▐█▐▐▌▐▀▀▪▄██▪  ██ ▄▄ ▄█▀▄ ▐█ ▌▐▌▐█·▐▀▀▪▄     ▐█.▪ ▄█▀▄     
▐█▌██▐█▌▐█▄▄▌▐█▌▐▌▐███▌▐█▌.▐▌██ ██▌▐█▌▐█▄▄▌     ▐█▌·▐█▌.▐▌    
 ▀▀▀▀ ▀▪ ▀▀▀ .▀▀▀ ·▀▀▀  ▀█▄▀▪▀▀  █▪▀▀▀ ▀▀▀      ▀▀▀  ▀█▄▀▪    
     ▄ .▄       ▄▄ • ▄▄▌ ▐ ▄▌ ▄▄▄· ▄▄▄  ▄▄▄▄▄.▄▄ ·            
    ██▪▐█▪     ▐█ ▀ ▪██· █▌▐█▐█ ▀█ ▀▄ █·•██  ▐█ ▀.            
    ██▀▐█ ▄█▀▄ ▄█ ▀█▄██▪▐█▐▐▌▄█▀▀█ ▐▀▀▄  ▐█.▪▄▀▀▀█▄           
    ██▌▐▀▐█▌.▐▌▐█▄▪▐█▐█▌██▐█▌▐█ ▪▐▌▐█•█▌ ▐█▌·▐█▄▪▐█           
    ▀▀▀ · ▀█▄▀▪·▀▀▀▀  ▀▀▀▀ ▀▪ ▀  ▀ .▀  ▀ ▀▀▀  ▀▀▀▀
```

Comment: What is the value of `contents`? Does your calculation still calculate a negative value if you use a simpler string, say "Hello, world!" or "█"?

Comment: Sorry for the delay. The content length value would be 642 if that's what you're after, the content contains just the ASCII art ill add this to the post. Using just a "Hello World" works and so does " █ ".

Upon messing with the text, It seems that what I am doing wrong is that I am only setting the cursor position to ONE LINE of the text but this is multi-lined thus the other lines get cropped up

Comment: My crystal ball says that "contents" includes the line breaks ("\r\n").  You must Split() it so you can use SetCursorPosition() for each individual line.